# How to wait for SQLCMD prompt to show

Tags: c#, process, sqlcmd

I'm running SQLCMD process, and I need to wait for the SQLCMD password prompt, and then insert it using StandardInput.
I can read any others outputs from the process, for example, outputs for a queries etc. but not for "Password:" prompt.

```cs
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, evt) => {
    if (evt.Data != null)
        Console.WriteLine(evt.Data);
    };

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Comment: Try using capital -Q instead of lowercase -q.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @jdweng but i want to wait for password input, not for the query to end

Comment: What an odd thing to do. Why not just use the normal `SqlCommand`?

Comment: @Charlieface : What is wrong with code?  SQLClient is very slow compared to SQLCMD.  SQLCMD is designed to work with huge databases.  I had issues years ago where SQLClient was taking over 1/2 hours while SQLCMD was taking seconds with same query.

Comment: @jdweng I think that's highly unlikely to be an issue with `SqlClient` (certainly not with the new `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` which is very performant) and much more likely to be an issue with [a differing query plan](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html), which is its own subject. If there was an issue with `SqlCient` being that slow then open a GitHu issue on it, because that has not been my experience even when dealing with big databases.

Comment: @Charlieface : The speed had to do with the driver.  I do not know if changes were made to the SQLClient drver connection to improve speed.   The Entity interface use to be much quicker than SQLClient.  Not sure if improvements have been made.